# From Excel sheet how to extract specific row with condition to be satisfy

Tags: python, .net, python-unittest

```
import xlrd
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("22nd report (1).xls")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
c=sheet.cell_value(0,0)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):#total no of columns is 11 
    x= sheet.cell_value(row,2)
    #print(x)
    c=str(x)
    A="18"
    p=int(c)
    if(A in c):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            print sheet.cell_value(x,col)
```

Showing error:- 
      Value error :invalid literal for literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your actual question is, but in the above code the value '1.0' cant be converted to int because it's the string representation of a float.

you might consider using `p = int(float(c))`

But then you never again use p.... so you might as well delete the line...